# Using special characters with Google Charts

Tags: c#, javascript, json, google-visualization

I'd like to use special characters with Google Charts, for instance having an apostrophe in a node name.

How can I do this? I have tried Unicode as well as UTF-8 and still I get a SyntaxError from Google.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried using the standard ASCII character encodings? http://www.yellowpipe.com/yis/tools/ASCII-HTML-Characters/index.php

Comment: Thank you @jacktheripper, that was exactly what I needed. I ended up using HttpUtility.HtmlEncode to do the conversion. If you post this as an answer then I'll be more than happy to mark it as correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the standard ASCII character encodings. A good list of them can be found [here](http://yellowpipe.com/yis/tools/ASCII-HTML-Characters/index.php), and an explanation can be found [here](http://everything.explained.at/ascii/).