# Google Chart title and column name with special characters

Tags: special-characters, google-visualization

The solution for what i am looking should be [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9143163/using-special-characters-with-google-charts). But, when i try to use ASCII character encodings, the ASCII code is actually printed. Any ideas why?

For example, i have the following code on Google Chart Option:

```
var optionsTotUsers = {
    'title': 'Transa&ccedil;oes',
    'backgroundColor': 'transparent',
    'height': '300',
    'legend': 'bottom',
    'vAxis': { viewWindowMode: "explicit", viewWindow: { min: 0} }
};
```

This prints the actual &ccedil on the chart title. If i use the 'ç' it prints out �.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think this will help you.Using UNICODE you can add special characters to the title. The UNICODE for the special characters is available [here](http://www.webtoolhub.com/tn561380-xhtml-characters-list.aspx).You need to use UNICODE as below.

```
var options = {
                'title': 'Transa\u00E7oes',
                'backgroundColor': 'transparent',
                'height': '300',
                'legend': 'bottom',
                'vAxis': { viewWindowMode: "explicit", viewWindow: { min: 0} }

            };
```

Click here to see the working sample. [jqfaq.com](http://jqfaq.com/how-to-add-special-characters-in-google-charts-title/)

Comment: I believe that this is the best solution. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 7):

if you are using jQuery, you can take advantage of the `html()` function

```
var options = {
   title: $('<div>Transa&ccedil;oes</div>').html()
   ...
};
```

[image]

**Edit** : Dont know why google charts is not able to parse a string with special HTML characters, or why there is not an option for declaring the title as HTML - even `<em>` and so on is rendered as text, but the above works.

Comment: This could be used as a quick fix if you can't do the UNICODE solution for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

The .html() function worked for me for the Chart title, but I needed to use the .text() function to get character codes to display for vertical and horizontal axes labels.